# how to use metrics with perf stat

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, perf-event

perf list shows a bunch of what it calls metrics. The list starts off with

```
List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):

Metrics:

  BAClear_Cost
       [Average Branch Address Clear Cost (fraction of cycles)]
  C2_Pkg_Residency
       [C2 residency percent per package]
  C3_Core_Residency
       [C3 residency percent per core]
  C3_Pkg_Residency
       [C3 residency percent per package]
```

I'd like to experiment with these but I can't get perf stat to use them. Since the first line says "(to be used in -e)", I tried the following, but it produces an error

```
103>   perf stat -e IPL  sleep 10
event syntax error: 'IPL'
                     \___ parser error
```

Then I found some examples on the internet using -M, but this doesn't work either.

```
103 >    perf stat -M IPL  sleep 10
Cannot find metric or group `IPL'

 Usage: perf stat [<options>] [<command>]

    -M, --metrics <metric/metric group list>
                          monitor specified metrics or metric groups (separated by ,)
```

Can someone explain how to get perf to use these metrics? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. It looks like using the flag `-M` should do the job. In your example, you used `-M IPL`, I'm not sure what `IPL` stands for. If you meant Instruction Level Parallelism, it should be ILP. So try using `-M ILP`